# publish dist folder to github pages

Tags: vue.js, github, github-pages, vue-cli

[My Code](https://github.com/Sh031224/every)

I want to publish to github pages
I use vue-cli version 4.x

When I enter my github page, I can only see my README.md.

[github page link](https://sh031224.github.io/every/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) can be:

- the master branch content
- the gh-pages branch content
- the `doc` subfolder

The `public/` subfolder is never considered for publication.

See [Vue.js GitHub Pages](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#platform-guides) for an example of deployment.
Also "[GitHub Pages + Vue CLI 3](https://dev.to/mejiamanuel57/github-pages-vue-cli-3-1cjo)" from [Manuel Mejia Jr.](https://twitter.com/mejiamanuel57).